# Linq to FileHelpers Class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file-io, filehelpers

I am trying to get the results of a linq query int a file. I created and array of the same type as the FileHelpers class I created, then queried the data and assigned the values to the array I just created.

I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The strange thing is that the item giving out the error is the one that is getting a value assigned to it. Not sure why this is happening:

```
NorthwindEntities dbContext = new NorthwindEntities();
        var q = from d in dbContext.Products
                select d;
        producdt[] items = new producdt[q.Count()];

        for (int i = 0; i < q .Count(); i++)
        {
            items[i].Field1 = q.ToList()[i].ProductName;
        }
        FileHelperEngine<producdt> engine = new FileHelperEngine<producdt>();
            engine.WriteFile("test.text", items);
```

including product class:

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]
public sealed class producdt
{

[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public String Field1;

[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public String Field2;

[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public String Field3;

[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public String Field4;

[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public String Field5;


}
```

Comment: Is `producdt` an object or a record? Also, this could be *heavily* optimised, your making 3 trips to the database here when really it could be done in one.

Comment: the error is on the line items[i].field1 = q.ToList()[i].ProductName;

Comment: Let me re-phrase - is `producdt` a class or a record?

Comment: producdt is a class:
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.ExactLength)]
public sealed class producdt
{

[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public String Field1;

[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public String Field2;

[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public String Field3;

[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public String Field4;

[FieldFixedLength(10)]
public String Field5;


}

Comment: The solution @dotNET has suggested will do the job for you. Not only that, it is more efficient as you will only be making 1 trip to the DB....at the minute you are making 3 at minimum.

Comment: when i use his suggestion i get the following error: Error 6 Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'producdt'

Comment: That sounds as though your trying to project an anonymous type to an array of `producdt`, are you using the code as written? Or are you writing `select new { Name = d.Name }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must initialize `items[i]` before using it in the `for` loop. The problem is that you have created the array, but its individual elements are `null`. I guess you'd want to assign the return of your linq query to this array, after doing some projection using `Select()`.

Though I don't know the specifics of your class, I suppose you'd do it on the following lines:

```
producdt[] items = (from d in dbContext.Products
                   select new producdt(){ 
                                          Field1 = d.Field1, 
                                          Field2 = d.Field2, 
                                          Field3 = d.Field3, 
                                          Field4 = d.Field4
                                         }).ToArray();
```

Comment: That is, assuming `productdt` is a reference type (which it most likely is), though it would have helped to know which line the error was occurring on exactly.

Comment: The WriteFile method accepts an IEnumerable so you can avoid the ToArray() too.
var items = (from d in dbContext.Products select new producdt(){ Name = d.Name });

Comment: this is the error when i try thet assignment above:
Error 6 Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'producdt'

Comment: @user2275571: Can you plz include the body of productdt class in your question?

Comment: check above...i've added the class

Comment: Updated my code. Then again I don't know the structure of your entity (Products), but I guess you should be able to easily expand my code.